# Laravel take skip query not taking valid data

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a Laravel blogging app.

I am trying to fetch articles in the database using a query builder but it doesn't seem to work for me.

What I want is to skip the top 3 latest articles and display only the 2 next articles (4th and 5th)

Here is my function:

```html
public function getIndex() {
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(3)->take(2)->get();
    return view('pages.home')->with(['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

My blade view is structured like this:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 top-post-right">
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div class="single-top-post">
            <div class="feature-image-thumb relative">
                <div class="overlay overlay-bg"></div>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="/storage/{{$post->image}}" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="top-post-details">
                <ul class="tags">
                    <li><a href="#">{{ $post->category->name }}</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="{{ url('article/'.$post->slug) }}">
                    <h4>{{ $post->title }}</h4>
                </a>
                <ul class="meta">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-user"></span>Mark wiens</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-calendar-full"></span>{{date('j M, Y',strtotime($post->created_at))}}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="lnr lnr-bubble"></span>{{ $post->comments()->count() }} Comments</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>                    
    @endforeach
</div>
```

This is printing all the articles, does anyone know where I messed up?

Comment: could you `dd($posts)` and dd(`Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(3)->take(2)->toSql())`? what is the output?

Comment: In your view you are iterating over `$posts_left` but you are passing `$posts` to your view from the controller. Try looking at `dd($posts)` to see if you are getting the records you expect and verify your view is correct.

Comment: Hi Tesa, What do you mean by dd??

Comment: Hi peter, I edited it and the results remains the same

Comment: how many articles do you have in your DataBase?

Comment: what type of error do you see in your browser when you try to fetch articles?

Comment: @Dejavu guy I have more than 10 articles

Answer (score 0):

this actually works on me as ive tried:

$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(3)->take(2)->get();

1.) your looking at the wrong blade file? or

2.) must be a cache problem, restart server.

Comment: Tried both(clearing caches & using that method but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: when you dd($posts); on the controller, does it show two records only or it also show all records?

Comment: also, have you tried running these: php artisan optimize, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan route:cache, php artisan view:clear, php artisan config:cache. This will reoptimized class loader, clear cache facade value, clear route cache, clear view cache and clear config cache. -just a thought.